# live stream in firefox (jplayer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer, live-streaming

I have a website which reproduces radios by html5.
I was having problems with firefox, so I decided to use jplayer plugin, but now I'm unable to play a live stream radio in firefox, the log says:

**El "Content-Type" HTTP de "audio/mpeg" no es compatible. Ha fallado la carga del recurso de medios http://www.domain.com**

I've created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XLNCY/5611/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function(event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://212.34.158.168:8490/stream",
            oga: "http://212.34.158.168:8490/stream"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/js",
    supplied: "mp3, oga"
});
```

});

Hope your help, Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function(event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: "http://212.34.158.168:8490/stream"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/js",
    supplied: "mp3"
});
```

I removed oga because the type of live stream is mp3.

Hope that helps, Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Convert your video to m4v

See jplayer doc:
Essential Audio formats: mp3 or m4a.
Essential Video format: m4v.

Counterpart formats: webma, webmv, oga, ogv, wav, fla, flv, rtmpa, rtmpv.